# Checking boolean values in 2d array

Tags: java

I'm trying to make 'The Game of Life' in Java. I made a 2d matrix and filled it with boolean values.

Now I'm trying to count the boolean values of adjacent cells that are true, but when I use `=`, I get all of the cells surrounding it (eg: a cell in the middle gives 8, a cell on a corner gives 3) and when I use `==`, I just get all 0's.

Example if statement (first one works, second doesn't work):

```
if(!celloc.equals("URC") && !celloc.equals("RightB") && !celloc.equals("LRC")) {
            if(current[i][j+1] = true) {
                life++; // right
            }}
```

Comment: You should try if(current[i][j+1] == true) {

Comment: If `current` is the array that contains the boolean values then `if(current[i][j+1])` is enough

Comment: Tried both,they give me 0's.

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please try to explain better.

Comment: Whats not clear exactly?

Comment: As a side note - best practice: !"URC".equals(celloc) instead of !celloc.equals("URC")

Comment: To receive specific help about a problem, you need to provide actual code. A [mcve] is what you should give us. Other than that, we can only tell you the difference between `=` (the assignment operator) and `==` (equality), since we can't really understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: 1. Check if a position tag , in this case, satisfies the if statement(this part works)
2. Check the positions around the block and execute life++ if they are true.
I cant upload the whole code because its 60 lines of the exact same statement + 140 of things irrelevant to this

Answer (score 1):

A single "=" is for assignment, use "==" when testing for equivalency.  Also, if "current[i][j+1]" is a boolean you can simply type:

```
if(current[i][j+1]) {
```

to test if that value is true.  You may be getting 0 because you may not be getting to that if statement.  Try adding some output to see if your first if statement is ever actually true.

Comment: I must be getting to the if statement because =  lets life count for all adjacent values. Tried ==,gives me 0's. same as if(current[i][j+1]).

Comment: Try other debugging statements to see what is going on. Make sure the values of i and j are actually what you expect them to be when it is checking, print out "current" if it is not too big.  It sounds like you never actually check a value of current that is true.

Comment: @user569685 : using a single '=' fulfills the if condition because of the value you used in the assignment - true. The value returned by an assignment is the assigned value. Using ' = true' will therefore always result in the condition being true.

Comment: I print out current previously in the code,also i use its coordinates so i know they're accurate. I dont wanna post the whole code because its 200ish lines.